# error about compiling c++ code with cmake and boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to compile c++ software depending on boost with CMake. With the same source code and CMakeLists.txt files, I succeeded with my own laptop (ubuntu 11 with boost1.42), but I am getting the following error message with my workstation (RHEL6.2 with boost 1.41) in research group (btw, boost1.41 should be enough):

```
main/main.cpp: In function ‘path
make_path(const std::string&)’:
main/main.cpp:50: error: invalid
conversion from ‘bool (*)(const std::string&)’ to ‘void*’
main/main.cpp:50: error:
initializing argument 2 of ‘boost::filesystem3::path::path(const Source&,
typename
boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem3::path_traits::is_pathable<typename
boost::decay<Source>::type>, void>::type*) [with Source =
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]’
main/main.cpp: In function ‘int
main(int, char**)’:
main/main.cpp:664: error: ‘class
path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
main/main.cpp:676: error: ‘class
path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
make[2]: *** [main/CMakeFiles/vina_main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [main/CMakeFiles/vina_main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't quite understand the error message and don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

======================= update =========================

The above error message is fixed thanks to your help, but I still get the error message indicating linking failure between my executable file and boost libraries. I did link it within CMakeLists.txt by 'target_link_libraries (vvv_main vvv ${Boost_LIBRARIES})'. The error message is like:

```
CMakeFiles/vvv_main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function              '__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

.......

I read other related posts here, but still have no clue how to fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us line 50 of main.cpp? And perhaps some context around that line?

Comment: Also, in line 664 you seem to be calling a none-existent method. I know that boost::filesystem v3 breaks many things of v2, so check the functions that were removed.

Comment: In line 50 of `main.cpp` you're instantiating a `boost::fileystem3::path` object. What is the second parameter you're passing to the constructor?

Comment: Are you sure this is version 1.41? Because v3 is only meant to be the default from Boost 1.46 onwards. The other thing is that `path::native_file_string` is deprecated and (I think) has been for a while. Whether Boost actually provides deprecated bits or not is controlled by a `#define`; maybe it's defined differently on your two systems.

Comment: @wilhelmtell Thank you. The line 50 is :'        return path(str, boost::filesystem::native);
'. The problem is due to default Boost filesystem version. But now I have some problem for linking executable file with boost library.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thank you for your comment. I just add one line to define macro for the version of filesystem in my main.cpp. The above error message disappears. But I have other issues for linking boost libaryies.

Comment: One question per question, please. Perhaps you're looking for a chatroom, where debugging issues may be addressed sequentially. This is a programming Q&A, not a "help site" _per se_.

Comment: You need to add Boost.System to your target_link_libraries. But please heed the advice about single questions.

Comment: `-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for your remind. I will remember it in the future, this is my first post.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, that you use the `find_package` routines of CMake together with the `required` flag and explicitly specifying the components you need. Then there is no need to manually set the libraries.

For your project

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.41 COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)
MESSAGE(STATUS "** Boost Include: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

together with

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(your_project ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

should do the trick. Specifying the version (here 1.41) makes CMake if only an older version of boost is available. Specifying the components (components = boost libraries that are not header-only) makes CMake complain if those are not available and also automatically adds those to the variable Boost_LIBRARIES. The Message statements are not necessary but I like to have some feedback...

In case you would like to manually download and install the newest version of boost (which I normally do since Linux distributions tend to be somewhat slow with respect to boost packaging) alongside the version provided by the system, then you can hint the find_package scripts for boost to the custom location via

```
SET(BOOST_ROOT "$ENV{HOME}/usr")
```

which of course goes before the `find_package` call (in this example boost would have been installed into the prefix $HOME/usr).

One last remark - I sometimes used to have problems with older versions of the `FindBoost.cmake` script (especially those from the old CMake 2.6) that does all the magic when `find_package(Boost)` is called. It should not be a problem for Boost 1.41, but in case there are problems finding (newer versions of) Boost even though you're absolutely sure it is correctly installed, you might want to try a more recent version of `FindBoost.cmake`. For example from the [gitweb](http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=tree), it should be in the `Modules` tree.

Comment: Janitor048, thank you. I did as you stated here, and the message from cmake indicates it can find boost. But I still cannot link the boost with my executable file. My cmake version is 2.8. I noticed when I yum install boost*.x86_64, there is no boost-system-devel. Could that be the reason? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: The message from cmake is:'-- Boost version: 1.41.0
-- Boost version: 1.41.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
--   system
--   thread-mt
--   serialization
--   filesystem
--   program_options'

Comment: -- ** Boost Include: /usr/include
-- ** Boost Libraries: optimized;/usr/lib64/libboost_python-mt.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libboost_python-mt.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libboost_serialization-mt.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libboost_serialization-mt.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so;optimized;/usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so;debug;/usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so
'.

Comment: I think you omitted the `components` part from the find_package command as you find too many components (you don't need them all, do you?). Could you edit your question and append your CMakeLists.txt? Especially the parts where you do the find boost and where you do the target_link_libraries(..) stuff. And importantly: Which error message do you get now? As apparently the boost::system library is installed and found, I would doubt that the header files (the devel package) are missing. But I don't really know the RedHat packaging so error messages will be helpful.

Comment: @Tao And maybe you could check whether the required header files exist under `/usr/include/boost`, especially if there is a folder called `system`